# How to Import excel file data to data table in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I am moving data from excel file  to datatable, where 10th row is column values .So i used following code by using EPPLUS library(OfficeOpenXml).When i moved to datatable the Columns are `Item,Description,Accountnumber,Tender,Levelnumbers`.I said these all are 10th row of the excel file, hence due to merging of top level columns it is coming in a sequence like `Item,Column1,Column2,Description,Column3,Column4,Column5,Tender,Column6,Levelnumbers`.I need a logic like first i need to skip null rows(no data) for column `Levelnumbers` then  Description column name should be moved to Column4 and current column of Description should be named like 'Edata', so the column sequence should be like `Item,Column1,Column2,Edata,Column3,Description,Column5,Tender,Column6,Levelnumbers`

So altogether by using following code i got values in data table like

```
Item,Column1,Column2,Description,Column3,Column4,Column5,Tender,Column6,Levelnumbers
1,null,null,Efax,null,Edescription1,null,Tfirst,null,123353
2,null,null,Zfax,null,Zdescription1,null,Tsecond,null,null
3,null,null,Xfax,null,Xdescription1,null,Tthird,null,456546
```

But it should come as like(skipped values which has Levelnumbers blank ),how to achieve it?

```
Item,Column1,Column2,Edata,Column3,Description,Column5,Tender,Column6,Levelnumbers
1,null,null,Efax,null,Edescription1,null,Tfirst,null,123353
3,null,null,Xfax,null,Xdescription1,null,Tthird,null,456546
```

code used is

```
public static DataTable getDataTableFromExcel(string path)
        {
            using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
            {
                DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
                    {
                        pck.Load(stream);
                    }
                    var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                    bool hasHeader = true; // adjust it accordingly( i've mentioned that this is a simple approach)
                    string ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[10, 1, 17, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
                    {
                        tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
                    }
                    var startRow = hasHeader ? 11 : 1;
                    for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
                    {
                        var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                        var row = tbl.NewRow();
                        foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                        {
                            row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                        }
                        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {

                }
                return tbl;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do i need to play with data table which i got instead of excel file?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking (let me know if not) you just want to be able to filter out rows missing a value in the last column?  Best to do an explicit cell reference call rather then trying something like `wsRow.Last()` because the `wsRow` range will only return cells that have values in it so the `Last()` will never return a reference to the last column cell since it would be null.

As for replacing column names, all you need is an `if` statement when populating the column list.

This should do it:

```
//foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[10, 1, 17, ws.Dimension.End.Column])  -- ASSUME YOU MEANT ONLY THE 10TH ROW?
foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[10, 1, 10, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
{
    if (!hasHeader)
        tbl.Columns.Add(string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
    else if(firstRowCell.Text == "Description")
        tbl.Columns.Add("Edata");
    else if (firstRowCell.Text == "Column4")
        tbl.Columns.Add("Description");
    else
        tbl.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
}

var startRow = hasHeader ? 11 : 1;
for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
{
    //Skip row if last column is null
    if (ws.Cells[rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column].Value == null)
        continue;

    var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
    var row = tbl.NewRow();
    foreach (var cell in wsRow)
    {
        row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
    }
    tbl.Rows.Add(row);
}
```